# Mysql left-join, count by unique value in a field not working

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table like below.

I want to be able to get a count of `group_id` then group by `group_id` then left join groups table where `groups_user.group_id = groups.id` but I'm only getting one result back.

I want group by unique `group_id` then count of each duplicate `group_id`. So far my query is like below:

```
SELECT 'groups.group' ,COUNT('groups_users.group_id') as groups_count
FROM `groups_users`
LEFT JOIN groups
ON 'groups_users.group_id' = 'groups.id'
GROUP BY 'groups_users.group_id'
```

Table:

```
id  group_id    user_id
26  3           1
22  2           1
19  1           1
20  1           2
21  1           4
```

Where am I getting wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've got the JOIN backwards. Try:

```
SELECT g.group, COUNT(gu.group_id) AS groups_count
    FROM groups g
        LEFT JOIN groups_users gu
             ON g.id = gu.group_id
    GROUP BY g.group;
```